# split strings in multiple columns of matrix/dataframe into new columns

Tags: r, arrays, string, dataframe, matrix

How can I split multiple columns of dataframe/matrix and save results as data frame?
Each cell has two characters but I want only one character per cell and other pair of character to the next.

I try these but still can't get resulting data frame back from the results after split is done

```
geno_splitted_ls <- apply(mGenotype, 2, strsplit, split="") #split each column

do.call("as.data.frame", geno_splitted_ls) #collect results as dataframe fails
lapply(geno_splitted_ls, data.frame) #collect results as dataframe fails
```

data looks like this

```
> dput(mGenotype)
structure(c("gg", "gg", "gg", "gg", "gt", "gg", "gg", "tg", "gg", 
"gg", "aa", "aa", "ac", "aa", "ca", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ac", 
"tt", "tt", "ct", "cc", "tt", "tt", "ct", "tc", "tc", "tt", "aa", 
"aa", "ag", "aa", "ga", "ga", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ag", "aa", "aa", 
"aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "tt", "tt", "tt", 
"tt", "tt", "gt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt"), dim = c(10L, 6L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("genotype1", "genotype2", "genotype3", "genotype4", 
    "genotype5", "genotype6")))
```

Comment: can you provide the desired output, even for just a row or two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse-based solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

genotype <- structure(c("gg", "gg", "gg", "gg", "gt", "gg", "gg", "tg", "gg", 
                        "gg", "aa", "aa", "ac", "aa", "ca", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ac", 
                        "tt", "tt", "ct", "cc", "tt", "tt", "ct", "tc", "tc", "tt", "aa", 
                        "aa", "ag", "aa", "ga", "ga", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ag", "aa", "aa", 
                        "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "tt", "tt", "tt", 
                        "tt", "tt", "gt", "tt", "tt", "tt", "tt"), dim = c(10L, 6L), dimnames = list(
                          NULL, c("genotype1", "genotype2", "genotype3", "genotype4", 
                                  "genotype5", "genotype6")))

genotype %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_split(.x, "", simplify = TRUE)))
#>    genotype1.1 genotype1.2 genotype2.1 genotype2.2 genotype3.1 genotype3.2
#> 1            g           g           a           a           t           t
#> 2            g           g           a           a           t           t
#> 3            g           g           a           c           c           t
#> 4            g           g           a           a           c           c
#> 5            g           t           c           a           t           t
#> 6            g           g           a           a           t           t
#> 7            g           g           a           a           c           t
#> 8            t           g           a           a           t           c
#> 9            g           g           a           a           t           c
#> 10           g           g           a           c           t           t
#>    genotype4.1 genotype4.2 genotype5.1 genotype5.2 genotype6.1 genotype6.2
#> 1            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 2            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 3            a           g           a           a           t           t
#> 4            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 5            g           a           a           a           t           t
#> 6            g           a           a           a           g           t
#> 7            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 8            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 9            a           a           a           a           t           t
#> 10           a           g           a           a           t           t
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a specific reason why R adds automatically .1, .2 etc. Or could we tweak this behaviour? Say just for fun start with .2 and then .1? Many thanks. I am just curious has nothing to do with your answer!

Comment: Hi @TarJae :)  Adding ".1" and ".2" is just the default; you can 'glue' your column names to suit (per https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/across.R#L29), e.g. `genotype %>% as.data.frame() %>% transmute(across(everything(), list(\`2\` = ~str_split(.x, "", simplify = TRUE)[1], \`1\` = ~str_split(.x, "", simplify = TRUE)[2])))` will start with "genotype1_2" then the next column will be "genotype1_1". The source code is 'complicated' but `across()` is very flexible

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot. Makes sense. I must use more the `glue` function!

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps a less concise version of the answer above by @jared_mamrot...

```
as.data.frame(mGenotype) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~ substr(.,1,1),
                .names = "first_{.col}")) %>% 
  mutate(across(genotype1:genotype6,
                ~ substr(.,2,2),
                .names = "second_{.col}")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!starts_with('genotype'))
```

But might be helpful if you are like me and need to see things step by step first.

Answer (score 2):

You may split at `MARGIN=1`, `unlist` elements and `t`ranspose.

```
apply(mGenotype, 1, strsplit, split="") |> sapply(unlist) |> t()
#       genotype11 genotype12 genotype21 genotype22 genotype31 genotype32 genotype41 genotype42 genotype51 genotype52 genotype61 genotype62
#  [1,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [2,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [3,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "c"        "c"        "t"        "a"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [4,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "c"        "c"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [5,] "g"        "t"        "c"        "a"        "t"        "t"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [6,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "g"        "t"       
#  [7,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "c"        "t"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [8,] "t"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "c"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
#  [9,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "c"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"       
# [10,] "g"        "g"        "a"        "c"        "t"        "t"        "a"        "g"        "a"        "a"        "t"        "t"
```

Just pipe into another `|> as.data.frame()` if you need a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Using `read.fwf` in `base R`

```
read.fwf(textConnection(do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(genotype), sep = ""))),
     widths = rep(1, max(nchar(c(genotype)) * ncol(genotype))))
```